# C write struct to file

Tags: c, struct

I am trying to save struct data to file. I saved the data this way.

```
node_trx * trx_list;
trx_list = calloc(1, sizeof(node_trx *));
trx_list->amount = "123123123";
trx_list->currency = 123;
trx_list->next_node = NULL;
if (1 != fwrite(trx_list, length, 1, f)) {
    //error
}
free(trx_list);
```

Here is my struct:

```
typedef struct {
  char amount;
  int currency;
  struct node_trx * next_node; } node_trx;
```

Main problem is after i saved struct to file and then after read, when print values, it is printing wrong values. For example: i stored currency as 123, then printed 6788576 this kind of numbers.

here is my reading code:

```
int read_last_trx_from_file (const char * file_name, node_trx * * trx, unsigned * trx_len)
{
  FILE * f;
  *trx = NULL;

  if (NULL == (f = fopen(tools_get_full_filename_const(file_name), "rb")))
  {
    return 2; //error
  }

  size_t fsize;
  fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
  fsize = ftell(f);
  fprintf(stdout, "file size: %zd\n", fsize);
  if (!fsize)
  {
    fclose(f);
    return 3; //no data
  } else {
    if (fsize == 1) {
        return 3; // no data
    }
  }

  rewind(f);
  if (NULL != (*trx = (node_trx *) calloc(1, fsize)))
  {
    if (1 != fread(*trx, fsize, 1, f))
    {
        fclose(f);
        free(*trx);
        return 2; //error
    }
  }
  fclose(f);

  *trx_len = fsize;
  return 0; //OK }
```

Main function that calls read function:

```
int display_trx() {
  node_trx * card_data;
     if (3 != read_last_trx_from_file(LAST_TRX_OBJECT, &card_data, &data_set_len)) {
          if (card_data != NULL) {
            printf("%s AMOUNT \n", card_data->amount);
            printf("%d CURRENCY \n", &card_data->currency);
        } 
     }
}
```

After i read this way , when i print amount data, segmentation fault error occurs. so why segment error occured?
And when i print currency, it printing 734364636 this kinda numbers. So why it prints wrong numbers. 
Or i only wrote pointer of struct to file?
Please help me guys.

Comment: You should end your c string with "\0", so "123123123" should instead be "123123123\0";

Comment: Tried this way , nothing changed. Same errors occur.Any idea?

Comment: 1) `trx_list = calloc(1, sizeof(node_trx *));` --> `trx_list = calloc(1, sizeof(node_trx ));`

Comment: What is `length` in your first code snippet?

Comment: 2) `trx_list->amount = "123123123";` but `char amount;` (Also Saving a pointer to a file has little meaning.)

Comment: It's definitely a big problem assigning a string to amount, which is just a single char.

Comment: length: sizeof(node_trx) , ty i will try this . and let you know what will happen .

Answer (score 1):

There are two obvious errors in your code.

1. In struct declaration, the type of amount is `char`, but when you initialize it in `trx_list->amount = "123123123";`, you assigned a string, or char[10] array (there is an extra one for NULL terminator).
2. In function `display_trx`, second `printf`, the result of `&card_data->currency` is `int *`, not `int`. If you want to print out currency, why don't follow the first print, use `card_data->currency` (without &)? You get that large number because you are printing pointer value implicitly converted into `int`, or the address of currency in card_data.

And there is one error which compiler will not warn you (because it is not syntactically wrong.). As BLUEPIXY said in the comments, when allocating and initializing trx_list, you should really use `calloc(1, sizeof(node_trx))`. You are allocating space for what pointer `trx_list` points to, not the pointer itself, so there should not be an asterisk in `sizeof`.

My suggestion is using a "smart" compiler, such as gcc, and enable warnings. This is a good practice (at least for me). Thank you!

Comment: THanks it really helps. :)